# How do I validate a wpf button using an object and display the text of one of that objects children?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an object of type Part that has some validation rules associated with it.  I have a button set up as the following

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding MyPart}" Command="{Binding LoadPart}"/>
```

This button has the following style applied to it

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonPartChooserValidation" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Background" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <converters:ValidationErrorsToBackgroundColorConverter/>
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.(Validation.Errors), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.Value[0]}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Acceptable value"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The button changes it's background appropriately but it is displaying the type of the object i.e. 'mynamespace.mypart' as the text in the button and not the property 'DisplayName' that I would like it to display.  I have tried to override the ToString() method to display the appropriate text, but that mucks w/ my RefreshProperties method to raise the propertychanged notification.  What am I missing?  What solutions have people come up with to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ContentTemplate property of the Button to a DataTemplate that defines the appearance of your `MyPart` object

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding MyPart}" Command="{Binding LoadPart}">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

> That works, but I was hoping for a styles based solution.

You can set the ContentTemplate property in a Style Setter as well:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonPartChooserValidation" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: That works, but I was hoping for a styles based solution.  Do you happen to know how to achieve that using styles?

Comment: You can set the ContentTemplate property in a Style Setter as well. I edited my answer to clarify this.